# Page Orientation when converting images to pdf using FPDF (python)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, fpdf

I am trying to convert a folder of images(jpg) into PDFs using FPDF. This code works great for the images in portrait format. For the images in landscape though it puts them on the portrait format. Is there a way to detect orientation and assign that to the pdf?

[image]

**updated code for fix**

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os

image_directory = r'C:\coolbro\test\yay\test'

extensions = ('*.jpg','*.png','*.gif')

imagelist=[]
for ext in extensions:
    imagelist.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(image_directory,ext)))

for imagePath in imagelist:


    cover = Image.open(imagePath)
    width, height = cover.size

    if height > width:

        pdf = FPDF(unit = "pt", format = "legal")

        pdf.add_page()

        pdf.image(imagePath, 0, 0, 600)

        destination = os.path.splitext(imagePath)[0]
        pdf.output(destination + ".pdf", "F")

    if width > height:

        pdf = FPDF("L", unit = "pt", format = "legal")

        pdf.add_page()

        pdf.image(imagePath, 0, 0, 0, 600)

        destination = os.path.splitext(imagePath)[0]
        pdf.output(destination + ".pdf", "F")
```

Comment: If all you want is images, you should look at img2pdf.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Comment**:  I was trying to find a way to read the orientation

```
if Y > X:
    # portrait
else:
    # landscape
```

---

Add `orientation = 'L'`, for instance:

```
fpdf = FPDF(orientation = 'L', unit = 'mm', format='A4')
```

Comment: Adding the orientation of L cuts off all of my portrait images now. I have folder with portrait and landscape images. Too many to sort through manually. It seems with the code you have to pick on or the other orientation. I was trying to find a way to read the orientation.

Comment: I updated my code using two "if" statements worked. Could this cause a problem or do I need to use "else"?

Comment: @ajd018: It's the same, but compute  `X <> Y` twice.